# Guards in a Haskell constructor or factory methods with visibility constraints

Tags: haskell, factory-pattern

Rather new to Haskell and experimenting I came across a problem which looks like I would want to use guards in a constructor. My real experiment is a bit more involved, but it comes down to something like

```
data X a = Zero
   | a==0 = Zero
   | otherwise = Some a
```

I know **this is wrong syntax**, in particular because `a` is a type variable, not a value variable, so `a==0` is nonsensical anyway.

The background is that the values `Zero` and `Some 0` shall be equal in all regards, I would even say *identical*. In fact I never want to construct a `Some 0`, this should be forbidden or, as drafted above, silently converted to `Zero` already in the constructor.

I would think there is a common idiom in Haskell for this. In Java I would just make the two constructors `private` and provide factory methods to create either one or the other with `some(0)` returning `Zero` instead of `Some(0)`. Is this how you would to this in Haskell too?

EDIT: Ok, googling some more I finally found the Haskell [Factory Function entry](https://wiki.haskell.org/Factory_function), which seems to be part of the answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To make a constructor private, just don't export it, e.g.:

```
module Foo (Bar, mkBar) where

data Bar = Zero | Some a | ...

mkBar :: Int -> Bar  -- exported smart constructor
mkBar a = ...
```

Users of the library can use the `mkBar` function to create a `Bar`, but not `Zero` or `Some ...`.

The key is the `Bar` in the export list. If you had specified:

```
module Foo (Bar(..), ...) where
```

then the constructors for `Bar` would also be exported.

Answer (score 1):

> In Java I would just make the two constructors private and provide factory methods to create either one or the other

[user5402's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32681692) covers how you can solve your problem by doing something analogous in Haskell. I just want to point out one easy to make mix-up in your question. In your pseudo-Haskell snippet...

```
data X a = Zero
   | a==0 = Zero
   | otherwise = Some a
```

... you are treating the `a` in `data X a` as it was a parameter for a constructor of `X` values, so that you would be able to e.g. test whether `a == 0`. However, that `a` is a *type* parameter. It can be substituted by different types, so that `X a` actually corresponds to a range of types such as `X Int`, `X Double`, `X String` and so forth. That is rather similar to how you can use Java generics to parametrise a class, as in a declaration such as `class X<A>`.

---

Using the common terminology, `X` is a *type constructor*, which takes a type and produces another type (e.g. from `Int` to `X Int`). The *value* (or *data*) constructors are the ones you specify after the equals sign. As you know, you can use them as regular values, that may or may not be functions depending on whether they take arguments. So if we do...

```
GHCi> data X a = Zero | Some a
```

... then `Zero` is a value of type `X a` for arbitrary `a`...

```
GHCi> :t Zero
Zero :: X a
```

... while `Some` is a function from `a` to `X a`:

```
GHCi> :t Some
Some :: a -> X a
```

---

As for the type constructor `X`, we do not speak of its type, but rather of its *kind*. Types and type constructors have kinds analogously to how values have types. The `:kind` (or `:k`) command in GHCi allows you to check kinds:

```
GHCi> :k Int
Int :: *
GHCi> :k X
X :: * -> *
```

`* -> *` means `X` takes a type and produces a type, as described above.